# Altium Designer - Cannot place keepout

Tags: altium

I am trying to place a keepout region, however when I go to the Place menu, the options are greyed out and I cannot click on them.

Comment: Do you have a license checked out?

Comment: As Photon said, check for license and if you have license and still facing problem, then reinstall software and check.

Comment: Yes I have a license checked out. All other Altium functionality is working. I have been copy and pasting the same keepout line, and those keepout zones have been working fine, but I may need to use a different keepout zone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the layer you want the keepout on

Comment: To be a useful answer, you should add a bit more to it. Give instructions on *how* to do your solution, and if possible provide screenshots. This will make sure people in the future who are having this problem will be able to solve it

Comment: Had the same issue and sure enough, I had the Top Solder layer selected and active. Switching over to TopLayer as the active layer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct! Select the Layer (bottom of screen) you need to place the KO on. Then, try the Place --> KO once again. No need to check License nor re-install. Thank you Colin Parker!